# Access DataTable Columns by Index

Tags: c#

I posed this question very poorly before. Let me clarify from an MSDN reference:

```
private void PrintValues(DataTable table)           
{           
    foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)          
    {           
        foreach(DataColumn column in table.Columns)         
        {           
            Console.WriteLine(row[column]);
            -->I'd like to reference 'column' by index so I can map to my List<Record>records object.
        }
    }
}
```

I need to convert a DataTable object to my own Record class that consists of three fields. The most direct approach seems to be to grab the corresponding DataColumns by index but I'm not sure that's possible? The only examples I can find use 'foreach'.

```
public class Record 
{   
    private string nameFormal;
    private string nameInternal;
    private string nameSpecial;     
}

Record sqlsGet() //return Record from DataTable
{
    //Connection c
    //DataAdapter a
    //DataTable t

    Record records = new Record();
    foreach(DataRow row in t.Rows)
    {
        foreach(DataColumn column in t.Columns)
        {
        //I'd like to do this:
            //records(row[0]).nameFormal;
        //records(row[1]).nameInternal;
        //records(row[2]).nameSpecial;
        }
    }
    return records
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over each row in your `DataTable`, and populate a list of `Record` objects, using LINQ:

```
List<Record> recordList
  = t.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(x =>
     new Record { nameFormal = x[0], nameInternal = x[1], nameSpecial = x[2] });
```

Answer (score 2):

`DataTable` contains more then one row, so you will probably get a `List<Record>` or `Record[]` array instead of single record.

```
List<Record> sqlsGet()
{
    var records = new List<Record>();
    foreach(DataRow row in t.Rows)
    {
        var record = new Record();
        record.nameFormal = row[0];
        record.nameInternal = row[1];
        record.nameSpecial = row[2];
        records.Add(record);
    }
    return records;
}
```

As you can see, you don't need to iterate over `t.Columns` with second `foreach`.

If you need only one `Record` returned you have to pick only one row from `DataTable`.

```
Record sqlsGet()
{
    var record = new Record();

    // pick one row
    var row = t.Rows[0];

    record.nameFormal = row[0];
    record.nameInternal = row[1];
    record.nameSpecial = row[2];

    return record;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming there is only 1 row, and therefore 1 `Record` due to the fact that your return type is `Record` and not `List<Record>`.

```
Record record = new Record();
var row = t.Rows[0];
record.nameFormal = row[0];
record.nameInternal = row[1];
record.NameSpecial = row[2];

return record;
```

If you want to return a list of records, then use a loop:

```
List<Record> records = new List<Record>();
foreach(var row in t.Rows)
{
    Record record = new Record();
    record.nameFormal = row[0];
    record.nameInternal = row[1];
    record.NameSpecial = row[2];
    records.Add(record);
}
return records;
```